# method to print checkov external modules downloading status

Tags: terraform, checkov

I'm using checkov to scan the static code for my terraform scripts. My terraform scripts internally imports few modules from private repo or public repos. Is there anyway to print the status of download of external modules. The problem is here as I my tf scripts downloads from multiple repos and when I execute scan it is taking some time to download. Sometimes it feels like it is stuck and not doing anything. It will be useful if it prints status like "downloading [https://mygitrepo.com/module1..."](https://mygitrepo.com/module1...%22)

thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

To get more information regarding the download, you could simply set the environment variable to `INFO`, before running checkov

```
LOG_LEVEL=INFO
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).